# Java EventHandler for a TexBox that Acts Whenever any Letter is Pressed?

Tags: java, event-handling

I have a variable that I want to write to from a textbox, but I want it to be written to automatically when the user types the text into it...  Is there an EventHandler to do this, or do I have to do something different?

Comment: What is a text box? AWT has a TextField and Swing has a JTextField. The solution is different depending on what you are using. Don't make up component names.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a Key Listener for that:

[Key Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Go ahead and add a key listener to your textfield.